# proving $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^{n-1}\left((n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right)}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}dx = \frac{b^{n-1}-a^{n-1}}{2(a+b)}$

Tags: calculus

How can we prove:: $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^{n-1}\left((n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right)}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}dx = \frac{b^{n-1}-a^{n-1}}{2(a+b)}$

I did not understand How can I start the above problem

So please help me

Thanks

Comment: Try to write the numerator so as to bring out $(x-a)(x-b)=x-(a+b)x+ab$ . BTW, are you sure that it's $+a$ and $+b$ in the integral's denominator, and not $-a$ and $-b$ ?

Comment: @Lucian it's definitely +a,b. Change them to negatives and not only is the identity not true, but the integral becomes immensely more difficult (and fails to converge even in the base case n=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function inside the integral sign is nothing else than the derivative of $\displaystyle\frac{x^n}{(x+a)(x+b)}$ . This can easily be intuited from the fact that $(x^n)'=n\cdot x^{n-1}$ and $\left(\frac1{x+a}\right)'=-\frac1{(x+a)^2}$ . If intuition is not one's strong suit, then simply expanding the expression in the numerator, and breaking up the initial fraction into a sum of three smaller ones, then using [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) and [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), will ultimately yield the desired result.